# How to not open a form if it is already opened in winForm?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

First of all, I want to clarify that similar questions like this, is already asked in stackoverflow but none of those solved my problem. So, before you mark my questions as a duplicate, please understand my problem first.

I have two `form` named `frmNewCustomer` and `frmCustomers`. Inside `frmCustomers` I have a `button` control named `btnNewCustomer` that opens `frmNewCustomer` whenever I click the `button`. These two forms are `MdiChildren` of another form named `WMS`. Now, I don't want to open a `form` if it is already opened. For that what I have done is this (Code for `frmCustomers`).

```
namespace WMS.Presentation
{
    public partial class frmCustomers : Form
    {

        Form newCustomer = new frmNewCustomer();

        public frmCustomers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnNewCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (newCustomer.IsDisposed)
                newCustomer = new frmNewCustomer();

            newCustomer.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
            newCustomer.Show();
            newCustomer.BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

Now suppose, I opened the form `frmCustomers` from the main `form (Form1)` menu. After that I clicked the button `btnNewCustomer`. So, I have to `form` opened now inside `Form1`. If I again click on the file menu of `Form1` and try to open `frmCustomers` it doesn't open a new form, it just `focus` on the opened instance of `frmCustomers` which is fine. This way I can `focus` on `frmNewCustomers` too.

Now, If I close `frmCustomers` while `frmNewCustomer` is opened then again open `frmCustomers` and try to `focus` on the opened `frmNewCustomers` by clicking `btnNewCustomer` it doesn't work. It opens a new `frmNewCustomer` which I don't want. I just simply want to focus on the opened instance of `frmNewCustomer`. What can I do to solve my problem? I am enclosing a[image] screenshot so you may have better understanding of my problem.

Comment: because your instance of frmCustomers  is closed (not in memory). And then you are making new instance of frmCustomers  so it will open new customer form one more time.

Comment: Why are you creating newCustomer form inside frmCustomers ? If that is the requirement then newCustomer 's parent should be frmCustomer. You should close all the instance properly with their children forms.

Comment: Yes, This is the requirement. So, I should also close `frmCustomers` if I want to close `frmNewCustomer`?

Comment: check my answer. newcustomer will be independent

Answer (score 0):

There are many proactive and reactive ways of doing this

However, you can use something like this, this will reactivate the `Form` if its open, or create it if its not.

```
public void OpenExclusive<T>(Form parent) where T : Form, new()
{
    foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (form.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {
            form.Activate();
            return;
        }
    }

    Form newForm = new T();
    newForm.MdiParent = parent;
    newForm.Show();
}
```

Usage

```
OpenExclusive<MyForm>(this);
```

***Note*** : written on SO and totally untested

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to close the `newCustomer` form while closing `frmCustomers` form.

```
namespace WMS.Presentation
{
    public partial class frmCustomers : Form
    {

        Form newCustomer = new frmNewCustomer();

        public frmCustomers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(FormClosing);
        }


        private void btnNewCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (newCustomer.IsDisposed)
                newCustomer = new frmNewCustomer();

            newCustomer.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
            newCustomer.Show();
            newCustomer.BringToFront();
        }

        private void FormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!newCustomer.IsDisposed)
                newCustomer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Wrote on SO. Did not test it. Please make necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that finds the open form by its classname, and if found opens it, and restores it when minimized.
When the function retuns false, the form will not be opened yet and you can open for the first time.
This works well with my in my winforms application

```
public bool CheckIfFormIsAlreadyOpen(string className)
{
    bool Result = false;
    className = className.ToUpper();

    int i = 0;
    while ((i < Application.OpenForms.Count) && (Application.OpenForms[i].Name.ToUpper() != className))
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (i < Application.OpenForms.Count)
    {
        Application.OpenForms[i].Show();
        Application.OpenForms[i].BringToFront();
        if (Application.OpenForms[i].WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
           ShowWindowAsync(Application.OpenForms[i].Handle, 9); // 9 = SW_RESTORE
        }

        Result = true;
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Usage :

```
if (!CheckIfFormIsAlreadyOpen("frmCustomers"))
{
    frmCustomers form = new frmCustomers();
    form.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    form.Show();
}
```